# Migration from azure git to github gives error file exceeds the limit of 100MB

Tags: github, azure-git-deployment

I'm trying to migrate azure git repository to github. For this I'm trying to follow below steps:

1. Cloned azure git repo on local machine
2. Changed the origin url
3. Now trying to push the repository to github

it gives "git push file exceeds the limit of 100MB" error.

When I checked for large file in repo, I found inside .git/objects/pack/pack.... there is a 195MB file.

I tried to remove that large pack file but it is necessary, which I cant remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github be default doesn't support files greater than 100 MB.

You have to enable GITHUB LFS for uploading large files.